# Horizontal Count SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I could not find my answer.

I am trying to take data that is horizontal, and get a count of how many times a specific number appears.

Example table

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Empid | KPI_A | KPI_B | KPI_C |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   232 |     1 |     3 |     3 |
|   112 |     2 |     3 |     2 |
|   143 |     3 |     1 |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I need to see the following:

```
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| EmpID | (1's Scored) | (2's Scored) | (3's Scored) |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|   232 |            1 |            0 |            2 |
|   112 |            0 |            2 |            1 |
|   143 |            2 |            0 |            1 |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I hope that makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it **certain** that there will **always** be exactly three KPI_x columns?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are counting data across multiple columns, it might be easier to unpivot your `KPI` columns first, then count the scores.

You could use either the UNPIVOT function or CROSS APPLY to convert your `KPI` columns into multiple rows.  The syntax would be similar to:

```
select EmpId, KPI, Val
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select 'A', KPI_A union all
  select 'B', KPI_B union all
  select 'C', KPI_C
) c (KPI, Val)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36cb9/3). This gets your multiple columns into multiple rows, which is then easier to work with:

```
| EMPID | KPI | VAL |
|-------|-----|-----|
|   232 |   A |   1 |
|   232 |   B |   3 |
|   232 |   C |   3 |
|   112 |   A |   2 |
```

Now you can easily count the number of `1`'s, `2`'s, and `3`'s that you have using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select EmpId,
  sum(case when val = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Score_1,
  sum(case when val = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Score_2,
  sum(case when val = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Score_3
from
(
  select EmpId, KPI, Val
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    select 'A', KPI_A union all
    select 'B', KPI_B union all
    select 'C', KPI_C
  ) c (KPI, Val)
) d
group by EmpId;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36cb9/2). This gives a final result of:

```
| EMPID | SCORE_1 | SCORE_2 | SCORE_3 |
|-------|---------|---------|---------|
|   112 |       0 |       2 |       1 |
|   143 |       2 |       0 |       1 |
|   232 |       1 |       0 |       2 |
```